# qn error in JOIN operation

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've a query that I can't run in Access because it's giving an Error in JOIN Operation.

What's wrong with this query?

```
SELECT *
FROM   (((((( 
tb_Fahrzeug AS fze
JOIN tb_Pinnummern AS tpi
ON tpi.SG = fze.Motor_SG)
JOIN tb_bauteile AS bau
ON bau.ID = tpi.Bauteil)
LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS fpl
ON fpl.ID = bau.[FC_Plus])
LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS fmi
ON fmi.ID = bau.[FC_Minus])
LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS fub
ON fub.ID = bau.[FC_Unterbrechung])
LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS fad
ON fad.ID = bau.[FC_Aderschl] )
WHERE  fze.ID = [forms] ! [frm_fahrzeug] ! [id];
```

Comment: I'm not usually a fan, but in cases like this you'll find it easier to begin with the query designer and then customize afterwards, it should at least avoid any join complications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "Inner Join" instead of JOIN keyword.

Comment: But it's the same (`join` and `inner join`).

Comment: Join and Inner Join are not same in MS Access

Comment: Are not same? then  why can use I instead JOIN ,Inner join?

Comment: There is no syntax with only "JOIN" keyword, the JOIN keywords are e.g. INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN

Comment: Sorry, my fault (I've been using MS Access about 10 years ago for very short time...thankfully). +1 :-). ps sorry, I've deleted my question in comment, because you've answered even before I've asked.